# I do not understand why some pings in my network do not work

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ping

I have an Aruba WiFi Bridge 501 that is linked into a WiFi network that leads to my company network. On my end i connected a HPE OfficeConnect 1820 and behind that i connected my laptop and another test device.

Here are some devices:

- random device that sits in the internal company network - 192.168.130.12 , different subnet
- WiFi Bridge IP (for managment access) - 192.168.169.213
- Laptop - 192.168.169.240
- Switch Management Interface - 192.168.1.10
- Device that sits in the same subnet via WiFi - 192.168.169.153

I can ping:

- Laptop -> WiFi Bridge
- Laptop -> Switch Management
- WiFi Bridge -> device on the company network, different subnet
- WiFi Bridge -> device on same subnet

I cannot ping:

- Laptop -> device on the company network
- WiFi Bridge -> Laptop (only one way ping?)
- Switch -> Any device
- Device on same subnet -> WiFi Bridge

Does anyone have an idea what the issue in such a seemingly trivial problem could be? From my understanding the Access Point Bridge and the Switch should not interfere on L3 so i dont understand why my pings are not going through, mainly how it is possible that i can ping the Laptop and the Client on the network *from* the management interface of the AP, but not directly from my Laptop?
Is there anything that could block pings on the AP? How is it possible that i can ping A->B, but not B->A?

Comment: Sounds like one of the devices is setup using NAT/firewall, allowing communications in one direction.

Comment: which one could it possibly be? both switch and AP are bare-minimum out of the box, and the switch cannot ping either wifi bridge or laptop?